# Converting tf.keras model to estimator makes loss worst

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I did an experiment to compare tf.keras's performance before and after conversion to estimator and got very different loss:
1) tf.keras model (No estimator)   : 1706.100 RMSE (+/- 260.064)
2) tf.keras converted to estimator : 3912.574 RMSE (+/- 132.833)

I'm sure I did something wrong in estimator conversion, or in the Dataset API but I could not isolate the root cause. Any help is appreciated.

It is related to my other post "Converting CNN-LSTM from keras to tf.keras brings down the accuracy".

partial code with No estimator

```
import tensorflow as tf
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import ConvLSTM2D
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import warnings

def model_fit_convlstm(train_supv, config, first_round):
    # train X shape = (48, 36) 
    train_x, train_y = train_supv[:, :-1], train_supv[:, -1]
    # train X lstm shape = (48, 36, 1)
    train_x_convlstm = train_x.reshape(train_x.shape[0], config['n_seq'], 1, config['n_steps'], config['n_feature'])
    #
    input_shape = (config['n_seq'], 1, config['n_steps'], config['n_feature'])
    # relu = tf.nn.relu
    relu = 'relu'
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(ConvLSTM2D(config['n_filters'], (1,config['n_kernel']), activation=relu, input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(config['n_nodes'], activation=relu))
    model.add(Dense(1))    
    adam = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
    # adam = 'adam'
    mse = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error
    # mse = 'mse'
    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=mse) 
    model.fit(train_x_convlstm, train_y, epochs=config['n_epochs'], batch_size=config['n_batch'], verbose=0)
    return model

def model_predict_convlstm(model, test_supv, config, first_round):
    test_x, test_y = test_supv[:, :-1], test_supv[:, -1]
    test_x_convlstm = test_x.reshape(test_x.shape[0], config['n_seq'], 1, config['n_steps'], config['n_feature'])
    if first_round.state:
        print('test X shape = {}'.format(test_x.shape))
        print('test X convlstm shape = {}'.format(test_x_convlstm.shape))
    #
    predictions = np.array([])
    for row in test_x_convlstm:
        test_x_convlstm_row = row.reshape(1, config['n_seq'], 1, config['n_steps'], config['n_feature'])
        yhat = model.predict(test_x_convlstm_row, verbose=0)
        # print(yhat)
        predictions = np.append(predictions, yhat)
    #
    return predictions
```

partial code with estimator conversion

```
import tensorflow as tf
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import ConvLSTM2D
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import warnings

def model_fit_convlstm(train_supv, config, first_round):
    # train X shape = (48, 36) 
    train_x, train_y = train_supv[:, :-1], train_supv[:, -1]
    # train X lstm shape = (48, 36, 1)
    train_x_convlstm = train_x.reshape(train_x.shape[0], config['n_seq'], 1, config['n_steps'], config['n_feature'])
    #
    input_shape = (config['n_seq'], 1, config['n_steps'], config['n_feature'])
    # relu = tf.nn.relu
    relu = 'relu'
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(ConvLSTM2D(config['n_filters'], (1,config['n_kernel']), activation=relu , input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(config['n_nodes'], activation=relu))
    model.add(Dense(1))    
    adam = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
    # adam = 'adam'
    mse = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error
    # mse = 'mse'
    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=mse) 
    print('model {}'.format(model))
    #
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
      warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
      estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model)
    #
    # train X lstm shape = (48, 36, 1)
    # numpy_input_fn takes x: train_x_lstm shape
    # print('model.input_names {}'.format(model.input_names))
    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x = {model.input_names[0]: train_x_convlstm.astype(np.float32)},
        y = train_y.astype(np.float32),
        num_epochs = config['n_epochs'],
        batch_size = config['n_batch'],
        shuffle = True
    )
    estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn)
    #
    return model, estimator

def model_predict_convlstm(model, estimator, test_supv, config, first_round):
    test_x, test_y = test_supv[:, :-1], test_supv[:, -1]
    test_x_convlstm = test_x.reshape(test_x.shape[0], config['n_seq'], 1, config['n_steps'], config['n_feature'])
    if first_round.state:
        print('test X shape = {}'.format(test_x.shape))
        print('test X convlstm shape = {}'.format(test_x_convlstm.shape))
    #
    predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x = {model.input_names[0]: test_x_convlstm.astype(np.float32)},
        y = None,
        batch_size=1,
        num_epochs=1,
        shuffle=False
    ) 
    yhat_list = estimator.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn)
    # print('yhat_list {}'.format(yhat_list))
    predictions = np.array([])
    for yhat_dict in yhat_list:
      for key, val in yhat_dict.items():
        # print('yhat = {} {}'.format(key, val))
        predictions = np.append(predictions, val)
    #
    return predictions
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in `Estimators`, but could it be the learning rate that differs between your experiments ? I can't see it anywhere in your code, the default value could be different for `Estimators`.

Comment: I add the learning rate specification as suggested but unfortunately the mse gap still exists.

Comment: adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)
mse = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=mse)

Comment: More observation from me. I tried another neural network method (MLP). In that case, keras and tf.keras prediction is very close. Conclusion is that the gap introduced by estimator conversion only happens to certain tf.keras libraries and layers.

Answer (score 0):

More observation from me. I tried another neural network method (MLP). In that case, keras and tf.keras prediction is very close. Conclusion is that the gap introduced by estimator conversion only happens to certain tf.keras libraries and layers.
The culprit are ConvLSTM2D and Flatten which I suspect tf.keras may have different default or slightly different algorithm.
The following example produces no gap in prediction performance

tf.keras

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
relu = tf.keras.activations.relu
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(config['n_nodes'], activation=relu, input_dim=config['n_input']))
model.add(Dense(1))
adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
mse = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error
model.compile(loss=mse, optimizer=adam, verbose=0)
# model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=config['n_epochs'], batch_size=config['n_batch'], verbose=0)
with warnings.catch_warnings():
  warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
  estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model)
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x = {model.input_names[0]: train_x.astype(np.float32)},
    y = train_y.astype(np.float32),
    num_epochs = config['n_epochs'],
    batch_size = config['n_batch'],
    shuffle = False
)
estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn)
```

keras

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(config['n_nodes'], activation='relu', input_dim=config['n_input']))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=config['n_epochs'], batch_size=config['n_batch'], verbose=0)
```